# Why can I access API in one component and cannot access it in another one?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on Movie Searcher in React. In the `Popup` component, I access `{selected.imdbRating}` and get the rating of a movie.

I try to do the same within a list of movies. I use `{result.imdbRating}` in result class, but it does not show any value.

However, `{result.Title}` gives me the title so it seems like I can access the API in this Component. The code (altho not mine, but pretty much the same) is under this Github: https://github.com/TylerPottsDev/react-movie-database

This is my Result component:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Result({ result, openPopup, }) {
    return (
        <div className="result" onClick={() => openPopup(result.imdbID)}>
            <img src={result.Poster} />
            <h3> <p className="rating.result???">{result.Title}</p></h3>
            <h3>Rating: {result.imbdResult} </h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Result
```

Comment: Could you provide the error?

Comment: Look at the comment below. Thanks

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment. Please fix that.

Comment: The popup and the result each use a different endpoint, so perhaps they don't return the same values. Look at this: http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=dfe6d885&s=back+to+the+future (your results, no imdbRating) and this http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=dfe6d885&i=tt0096874 (which has a rating).

Answer (score 1):

imdbRating does not exist in the result object in Result.js file to achieve what you want i made a correction to your code just update the following files

```
// App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Search from "./components/Search";
import Results from "./components/Results";
import Popup from "./components/Popup";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    s: "",
    results: [],
    selected: {}
  });
  const apiurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=dfe6d885";

  const search = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      axios(apiurl + "&s=" + state.s).then(({ data }) => {
        let results = data.Search;

        setState(prevState => {
          return { ...prevState, results: results };
        });
      });
    }
  };

  const handleInput = e => {
    let s = e.target.value;

    setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, s: s };
    });
  };

  const openPopup = data => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, selected: data };
    });
  };

  const closePopup = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, selected: {} };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Movie Database</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <Search handleInput={handleInput} search={search} />

        <Results results={state.results} openPopup={openPopup} />

        {typeof state.selected.Title != "undefined" ? (
          <Popup selected={state.selected} closePopup={closePopup} />
        ) : (
          false
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


// Result.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Result({ result, openPopup }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    axios(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=dfe6d885&i=${result.imdbID}`).then(
      ({ data }) => {
        setState(data);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="result" onClick={() => openPopup(state)}>
      <img src={result.Poster} />
      <h3>
        {result.Title} <br /> {state.imdbRating}{" "}
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Result;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since ratings are in array then you have to access the item by index so you have to get it by index or key like result.Rating[0].Value something like that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're trying to get "Rating: {result.imbdResult}"
"imbdResult" doesnt seem to exist, shouldn't it be "imdbRating" here instead?

Answer (score -1):

I don't get any errors either in react or web console, but this is a sample result of my search:

```
 {Title: "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2", Year: "2011", Rated: "PG-13", Released: "15 Jul 2011", Runtime: "130 min", …} Title: "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2" Year: "2011" Rated: "PG-13" Released: "15 Jul 2011" Runtime: "130 min" Genre: "Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Mystery" Director: "David Yates" Writer: "Steve Kloves (screenplay), J.K. Rowling (novel)" Actors: "Ralph Fiennes, Michael Gambon, Alan Rickman, Daniel Radcliffe" Plot: "Harry, Ron, and Hermione search for Voldemort's remaining Horcruxes in their effort to destroy the Dark Lord as the final battle rages on at Hogwarts." Language: "English" Country: "UK, USA" Awards: "Nominated for 3 Oscars. Another 45 wins & 91 nominations." Poster: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyZGU4YzUtNDkzYi00ZDRhLTljYzctYTMxMDQ4M2E0Y2YxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIzOTk5ODM@._V1_SX300.jpg" Ratings: Array(3) 0: {Source: "Internet Movie Database", Value: "8.1/10"} 1: {Source: "Rotten Tomatoes", Value: "96%"} 2: {Source: "Metacritic", Value: "87/100"} length: 3 __proto__: Array(0) Metascore: "87" imdbRating: "8.1" imdbVotes: "718,729" imdbID: "tt1201607" Type: "movie" DVD: "11 Nov 2011" BoxOffice: "$381,000,185" Production: "Warner Bros. Pictures" Website: "N/A" Response: "True" __proto__: Object
```

imdbRating: "8.1" seems accessible, but my component does not read it